# Will entropy change in a steam , ice cube system?

Tags: thermodynamics

If a system has steam and ice cubes and after some time liquid water is all that's left, what happened to the entropy?

Comment: Unclear what your initial conditions are, is the system adiabatic, ...

Comment: Have you tried to do some calculations on some focus problems of this type?  (It's a really simple calculation).  Of course, if the change is spontaneous in an isolated system, we know without calculations that the entropy will increase.

Comment: Here is a sample problem for you to try.  You have 1 kg of ice at 0C and 1 kg of steam at 100 C and 1 atm in a rigid container, separated initially by a non-thermally-conductive partition.  At time zero, you remove the partition, and allow the system to evolve until thermodynamic equilibrium is achieved.  What is the final state of the system? What is the change in entropy of the system?

Comment: This question was on my university final exam. It stated that if you have an isolated system containing an ice-cube and steam. You close the lid and observe later that it is liquid water now. Does this observation violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics? My thinking was that as no heat left the system the overall entropy of system did not change.

Comment: That is an incorrect assessment.  The change in entropy is not equal to the integral of dq/T; it is equal to the integral of $dq_{rev}/T$, where the subscript rev refers to a reversible process path.  So you need to dream up a reversible process that takes your system from the initial thermodynamic equilibrium state to the final thermodynamic equilibrium state if you want to determine the change in entropy quantitatively.  But, for this problem, Clausius inequality tells us that, for a spontaneous process in an isolated system, the change in entropy of the system is always positive.

Comment: If you solve the problem I described in my previous post, even though no heat enters of leaves the system, you will find that the change in entropy is positive.